# SQL query for calculation stock as report Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with sql query. I have 2 tables :
1. TbPermission {id,itemName,qtyQuota,priceQuota,taxQuota}
2. TbProccess {id,permissionId,qty,price,tax,dateTime}

In my scenario,each trader who have permission to import goods will submit their data into tbProccess.
As result, quota on tbPermission will decrease (qty,price,tax).
I want to make a report table that have column {id.itemName,qty,qtyStock,price,priceStock,tax,taxStock,dateTime}   according that proccess like picture bellow :

[picture link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPhmF.png)

Thanks for your help...

Comment: This sounds like homework, but I don't see much effort.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Please add code snippet if you have tried something,

Comment: And no pictures, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your final code will be something like:

```
select per.id,itemName,qty,qtyStock,price,priceStock,tax,taxStock,dateTime
from TbPermission per
join TbProccess pro
on per.id = pro.id
```

sounds like you need an update statement to decrease their permission quantity

```
update TbPermission
set qtyQuota = qtyQuota-1,
priceQuota = priceQuota-1,
taxQuota = taxQuota-1
where id = 666
```